# I have declared a callback function and I want to call it....but failed....how can I call it directly?

Tags: javascript, function, callback

Coded function for a class....and the definition in the class...the function gets called at the start...how to prevent this and call it like in function test....which give the described error?

...

```
// ==========================================================================================
// Action class - coded for onMsg to bring it to work....please change if needed
// ==========================================================================================
let action = new class Action {
    constructor() {
        this.msgFunction = (msg) => { msg };
        this.msg = { message: 'Hello!', to_user: 'PeterPan', from_user: 'AlexanderTheGreat' };
        this.onMsg = (MsgFunction) => { MsgFunction(this.msg) };
    }
}

// ==========================================================================================
// action functions: directly called at start - please NOT change
// ==========================================================================================
//let totalTokens = 0;
action.onMsg(function(msg) {
    console.log('==== onMsg ====');
});

// ==========================================================================================
// This is what I want: call the onMsg functions at any time!
// got error:
//      index.js:8 Uncaught TypeError: MsgFunction is not a function
//          at Action.onMsg (index.js:8)
//          at test (index.js:22)
//          at <anonymous>:1:1
// when I write "test()" in the console!
// ==========================================================================================
function test() {
    console.log('==== test ====')
    action.onMsg(action.msgFunction(action.msg));
}
```

...

Comment: Your error is coming from this line. `this.onMsg = (MsgFunction) => { MsgFunction(this.msg) };` .. What is the definition of `MsgFunction` ?

Comment: @KiaiFighter - `MsgFunction` is just the name of the parameter.

Comment: I posted an answer. I hope it helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In JavaScript, you can pass a reference to a function as an argument. In your code, on line 8 (where the error is) it says the argument you are passing (line 2 of `test()`)

For example: `var myFunc = action.msgFunction` is a reference to a function so you can call it later.
Whereas `action.msgFunction(action.msg)` is whatever is returned by this function.

Your code should look like this:

```
function test() {
    console.log('==== test ====')
    action.onMsg(action.msgFunction);
}
```

Comment: Now it "runs"....still I have not the possibility of execute the code of 

"action.onMsg(function(msg) " which was my intention...